# How to show different icons for status bar and notification bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I'm creating android notification according to [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). I used large icon and small icon for Notification bar.

In this case small icon is showing on both **status bar** and  **notification bar** . I want to show different icons for status bar and notification bar, how i can achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different API's for each. See below:

```
Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("title")
    .setContentText("content")
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
    .setTicker(s.getText());
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon%28int%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setLargeIcon%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29

OR

As an alternative, you could use a custom notification layout.

Comment: Yes, i created notification as the same you described. But this method ".setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)" is show small icon at Notification bar AND at status bar. Is that right ? If yes, i want to use iconA.png for Status bar icon and iconB.png for small icon at Notification bar, how can i do that?

Comment: No. If you meant icon no.5 in the link. It will be same

Comment: so there is no way to use different icon for that ? Only small icon will show on both at status bar and notification bar ?

Comment: Oh i forgot that, that could be the solution. Thanks you.

Comment: And please edit your answer for "custom notification layout" so i can accept that.

Answer (score 9):

[In the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html); there are notification area and notification drawer, i think in your case status bar means the notification area. You can use the following code to create a notification by setting both small icon and large icon.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_icon);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo).setLargeIcon(bm).setContentTitle("title").setContentText("body");
```

Large icon is a bitmap and it is shown in notification drawer, small icon is shown in notification area but also in the notification drawer, in the bottom right corner of the large icon. [**It must be entirely white**](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification). If the small icon is colorful, it is shown as a white square in the notification area.

Comment: how to make the small icon **entirely white**?

Comment: @HammadNasir simply in your android studio click new image assets then choose icon for notification and status bar then choose your image and android studio will create the right icons.